Abrir un .docx en Python y esperar cierre de Word
estoy generando un codigo para abrir un .docx que funciona ok con os.startfile('demo.docx')
El tema es que me abre el Word y lo cierra casi instantáneamente. En Clarion tenía una función "isrunning()" que mientras corría el Word, se mantenía en un bucle. Una vez cerrado, isrunning daba un False y pasaba el foco al programa y continuaba. Hay alguna forma de hacer lo mismo?
Gracias!

Podes usar psutil para verificar si el proceso de Word esta activo y mantener el bucle hasta que el proceso haya terminado.
primero instala el módulo psutil:
pip install psutil

despues podes usar un script para abrir el archivo .docx con os.startfile() y verificar si el proceso de WINWORD.EXE esta corriendo, igual que como lo hacías con isrunning() en clarion.
Te dejo un ejemplo de referencia:
import os
import psutil
import time

def is_word_running():
    """Verifica si Word está corriendo"""
    for process in psutil.process_iter(['name']):
        if process.info['name'] == 'WINWORD.EXE':
            return True
    return False

def open_doc_and_wait(file_path):
    """Abre el archivo .docx y espera a que se cierre Word"""
    os.startfile(file_path)
    
    # aca esperas mientras Word esta corriendo
    while is_word_running():
        time.sleep(1)  # Esperar 1 segundo antes de volver a verificar

    print("Word se ha cerrado, volviendo al programa principal.")

# usa la funcion
open_doc_and_wait('demo.docx')

tené en cuenta que el codigo esta hecho para entorno windows, donde existe WINWORD.EXE.
Saludos.
